# Look_down problem finding the

Tags: perl

Im trying to get my ip address from whatismyipaddress.com and Ive found the details of the corresponding div using firebug, but im having trouble retrieving the contents.

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($resp->content);
my @colors = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'span class', class => 'ip blue' );

foreach(@colors)
 {
 print $_;
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing that's certainly wrong is:

```
_tag => 'span class'
```

this should be:

```
_tag => 'span'
```

But also note the following in the HTML source:

```
<!-- contact us before using a script to get your IP address -->
```

That is, they don't appreciate you doing this without permission...  Aside from the legal issues, they might also block the default LWP user agent.  You can override that, but that doesn't solve the legal issues.